# How do I find the database or table from embedded SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I am proficient in SQL but not so much in C#. Recently a web application has broke. I am trying to find the data in the SQL database that is entered through the web application. I am confused about where the SQL table and fields are in var query 1 and 2. See attached image.

[image: Var query]

Comment: I can't view the image. Can you copy the relevant data into the question?

Comment: The Code you submitted is in C# LINQ to Entities, and it does not contain an update to the DataBase.

Comment: As @DaniDev states - it's LINQ, not embedded SQL.  A tool like LINQPad would help you debug this.

Comment: The connection string used by Entity Framework is stored in your application's configuration file. This image doesn't contain any relevant information. Check the line that instantiates `context` and the config file itself

Comment: what is the specific issue that you are trying to solve? Are you wanting to understand the queries you posted and where (which tables) they are coming from? or are you trying to identify the code where the Update is happening or not happening? or both?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Entity Framework, and it would depend on how the mappings are setup, this is usually done either with an EDMX, or using code first with fluent mappings.

So you'll have to look at your mappings, to see what

- _ICL_RESENTS_INCOMEDTLS,
- _ICL_RESENTS_PAYMENTs,
- CDCLIENTS

entities are mapped to which tables. This mapping should tell you what the underlying tables are.

Comment: My apologies, from reading the question I thought he was looking specifically for tables from query1 and query2. I assumed he already knew the data was broken.